# Flutter : Prepare list data from http request

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use Flutter Tagging Plugin (https://github.com/sarbagyastha/flutter_tagging). During the testing it is working fine with hard coded list. Now, I am changing it to make call to database and show the list based on that.

Database is returning the data and JSON Parse is also showing the data.

However, I am not able to use that data in Flutter Tagging. As I do not have good knowledge on Flutter.

Here is the code which is working fine when using hard-coded list.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_syntax_view/flutter_syntax_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tagging/flutter_tagging.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

///
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Tagging Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

///
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _selectedValuesJson = 'Nothing to show';
  List<Language> _selectedLanguages;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _selectedLanguages = [];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _selectedLanguages.clear();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Tagging Demo'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: FlutterTagging<Language>(
              initialItems: _selectedLanguages,
              textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.green.withAlpha(30),
                  hintText: 'Search Tags',
                  labelText: 'Select Tags',
                ),
              ),
              findSuggestions: LanguageService.getLanguages,
              additionCallback: (value) {
                return Language(
                  name: value,
                  position: 0,
                );
              },
              onAdded: (language) {
                // api calls here, triggered when add to tag button is pressed
                return Language();
              },
              configureSuggestion: (lang) {
                return SuggestionConfiguration(
                  title: Text(lang.name),
                  subtitle: Text(lang.position.toString()),
                  additionWidget: Chip(
                    avatar: Icon(
                      Icons.add_circle,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    label: Text('Add New Tag'),
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 14.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                    ),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  ),
                );
              },
              configureChip: (lang) {
                return ChipConfiguration(
                  label: Text(lang.name),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  deleteIconColor: Colors.white,
                );
              },
              onChanged: () {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedValuesJson = _selectedLanguages
                      .map<String>((lang) => '\n${lang.toJson()}')
                      .toList()
                      .toString();
                  _selectedValuesJson =
                      _selectedValuesJson.replaceFirst('}]', '}\n]');
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: SyntaxView(
              code: _selectedValuesJson,
              syntax: Syntax.JAVASCRIPT,
              withLinesCount: false,
              syntaxTheme: SyntaxTheme.standard(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// LanguageService
class LanguageService {
  /// Mocks fetching language from network API with delay of 500ms.
  static Future<List<Language>> getLanguages(String query) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), null);
    return <Language>[
      Language(name: 'JavaScript', position: 1),
      Language(name: 'Python', position: 2),
      Language(name: 'Java', position: 3),
      Language(name: 'PHP', position: 4),
      Language(name: 'C#', position: 5),
      Language(name: 'C++', position: 6),
    ]
        .where((lang) => lang.name.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
        .toList();
  }
}

/// Language Class
class Language extends Taggable {
  ///
  final String name;

  ///
  final int position;

  /// Creates Language
  Language({
    this.name,
    this.position,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [name];

  /// Converts the class to json string.
  String toJson() => '''  {
    "name": $name,\n
    "position": $position\n
  }''';
}
```

I have create a http request function as below.

```
class LanguageService {
  /// Mocks fetching language from network API with delay of 500ms.
  static Future<List<Taggable>> getLanguages(String query) async {
    List searchlists = [];
    String searchvalue = query;
      var dtguid = 10;
      var dtgname = 'Test';
      int count = 0;
      String nodata;

    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), null);
    if(searchvalue.length > 2 && searchvalue.length < 15 ){
      searchlists.clear();
    try{  
      var deviceid = '1234';
      var dtgUid = '10';
      dtguid = dtgUid;
         print(searchvalue);

      var body = { "uid" : dtgUid, "deviceid": deviceid, "searchtext": searchvalue};
      var url = 'http://192.168.100.4:8080/search_tags.php';

                    // Starting Web API Call.
           var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(body)).timeout(Duration(seconds: 5),
            onTimeout: (){

              return null;
            });
         if(response.statusCode == 200){
           final data = getTagsFromJson(response.body);
                
                        var totalrec = data.content.length;
                        print('hi $totalrec');
                      if(data.content.length > 0 && data.content[0].tagname != 'Empty'){
                        for (var i in data.content) {
                          searchlists.add(i);
                            print(i.tagname);
                        }  
                      }else{
                        nodata = 'No Record Found';
                      
                      }

                print(searchlists.length);
                
         }
     
    }catch(e){
       print("Exception Caught: $e");
     
    }
 return searchlists;
    }else{
      return null;
    }
```

Here is the JSON Parse File.

```
GetTags getTagsFromJson(String str) => GetTags.fromJson(json.decode(str));

class GetTags {
    List<Content> content;
    bool success;
    String error;

    GetTags({
        this.error,
        this.content,
        this.success,
    });

    factory GetTags.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GetTags(
        error: json["error"],
        content: (json["content"] as List).map((x) => Content.fromJson(x)).toList(),
        success: json["success"],
    );


}

class Content {
    String tagname;


    Content({
        this.tagname,
    });

    factory Content.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Content(
      
        tagname: json == null ? 'Empty' : json["tagname"]

    );

    
}
```

Comment: What's the problem ? I mean error ??

Comment: @NaveenAvidi I don't know how to convert it.

Comment: use paste Json as Code Extension to generate dart model classes from response, You don't need to write boiler plate code for the conversion. this is the link : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=quicktype.quicktype

Comment: JSON Parse code is generated from app.quicktype.io. I am not sure what exactly you want to say. I have added the plugin details in the question.

Comment: Can you post the sample of json ??

Comment: Could you provider full sample json string and ping my name, thanks

Comment: Thanks  a lot guys. I managed to fix most of the part. Just testing few things. Once done i will post the answer.