# How to get current cursor position in TextFormField (preferrably using TextEditingController)?

Tags: flutter, tagging, cursor-position, textformfield, texteditingcontroller

I am trying to implement the 'Tagging users in comments' feature similar to Instagram.

Requirements:

- A list of users should be shown when a user types one or more characters after '@'.
- The term to be queried can be anywhere in the text and not just at the end.
- There can be more than one tagged user.

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59878228) answer for user-tagging in Flutter, but it shows a suggestion list only if the tag is at the end of the text while typing. It would be great if I could modify this behavior based on the current cursor position in the `TextFormField`. I looked at the `TextEditingController` API to find something similar but could not find anything useful.

Is there any way to get such information or am I missing something?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController/selection.html

Comment: Thanks, @pskink. `baseOffset` in TextSelection is just what I required.

Answer (score -2):

As per your requirements:

- If you want to display the user list after `@`, You may have to create a Widget that can show as a popup with the list of users. For that, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/57846261/1318946
- **queried can be anywhere in the text and not just at the end,** For that you can use https://pub.dev/packages/rich_text_controller
- For the multiple mentions, Use this one https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mentions

Other useful packages: https://pub.dev/packages?q=mention

**Note: As you haven't provided any code, I can't give a proper solution, but all the links will be helpful to get your solution.**

Comment: Thanks, Pratik. Not exactly the answer to the question but thanks for going out of your way to suggest helpful links. I'll check them out.